# New PSU will not Start - Only flashes when the switch is turned on

Tags: power-supply

[image: Mini-Cloud Project]

I purchased a shiny new Tier 4 power supply, a RaidMax 500W Cobra Power.

I have dismantled it to use as a power supply for my mini-cloud project.  I am porting the +12V rail to power 4X Intel NUC 5i5MYBE blades through a 12V to 18V 285W step-up DC transformer, the 5V rail to power my managed 5-port gigabit network switches and thrift store wireless router using 5V to 12V step up transformer modules, 3X 500GB USB3 hard drives for Cinder storage on the 3 compute blades, 3X Raspberry Pi 3B units (Swift Object Store w/WD Labs 333GB PiDrive kits,) and 1X Raspberry Pi 3B MaaS controller.

I have connected the brown "sense" wire to the 3.3V rail inside the PSU case and shortened the leed, although I should probably keep it full length and attach it to a full length 3.3V leed, while I do not think this is the source of my issue.

I have connected +12V Power indicator and +12V power-on indicator leads to colored 3mm LEDs as indicators, have wired the green power leed to a switch to turn the supply off and on, and have attempted turning the unit on and off with and without 10W dummy load resistors on the +12V or +5V rails.  I have attempted the following resistor combinations:

```
1X 10ohm
2X 10ohm parallel and serial (5ohm/20ohm)
1X 50ohm
2X 50 ohm parallel (25ohm)
```

The power supply power indicator LED stays lit when the unit is plugged in and stays on well after power is removed as it drains the capacitors.  The power-on LED flashes when i hit the switch, as do the connected components, but does not stay on when I turn it on.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but am running out of things to try.  I am not confident that connecting the sense wire to the +5V rail is a good idea, but that is the only other thing I can think of to try.

Comment: Is the PS_ON connector (green wire) shorted to ground? This usually is needed for the power supply to fully turn on.

Comment: "have wired the green power leed to a switch to turn the supply off and on" - Known and done.  Thanks.

Comment: Since you were unable to provide any useful suggestions and closed this I cannot answer it.  For shame.  The answer?  I accidentally soldered the sense wire to the +12V rail instead of the +3.3V rail.  The unit determined on startup that the +12V current that it was getting back over the sense wire was way out of bounds and more than it could correct for, so it shut the PSU down to prevent damage.  Connecting the sense wire to the rail with the proper voltage fixes the problem.  You should re-open this because this is common to most PSUs in the world, and this solution is not posted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

PC power supplies are connected to the motherboard - not only for giving the power, but also for getting some control signals. Check that you are not turned your PSU off by leaving some of the motherboard signals unnoticed or into the wrong logic state.

Comment: Here is what I have:

green - power sw
brown (sense) - +3.3v rail
purple - power connected (purple > 100k ohm resistor > 12V led > gnd)
gray - power on (gray > 100k ohm resistor > 12V led > gnd)

I used this guide to set it up:  http://makezine.com/projects/computer-power-supply-to-bench-power-supply-adapter/

Thanks.

Comment: The only other wires are blue: -12V (not needed), and white -5V (not needed)

Answer (score 1):

Turning on and off over and over again is in most of the cases a sign for a short circuit. I've no idea what the *brown "sense" wire* should be.
To turn the PSU on connect Pin 5 of the ATX connector to GND.

Here is a pinout of the [ATX plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#ATX12V_v2.4)

**Update**: In your picture is a purple wire connected to a black wire. The purple wire is the +5V Stand by supply, which is present even if the PSU is not turned on. Do NOT connect this to GND!

Comment: Per the guide I have been using:  "The purple wire is the +5 "stand by" power. This outputs a 5V signal even if the rest of the power supply has not yet turned on, allowing you to power any circuit that might control the ON/OFF signal." - Purple > 100K ohm resistor > LED > GND to indicate that the PSU has power/is plugged in.

Comment: "I've no idea what the brown "sense" wire should be." - the Sense wire detects the ACTUAL voltage at the load end of the rail and adjusts the voltage up or down to keep the actual power being delivered to the load as close to 12V, 5V, and 3.3V as possible to prevent incorrect operation due to the voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

Logic loads tend to be more linear driving buck regulators for the CPU than boost regulators. The reasons are difficult to explain but ATX power supplies generally only regulate the main 5V supply and the others are regulated by tight ratio coupling of the transformer ratios with rectifier diodes.

There are limits to cross-load regulation errors and dynamic load regulation errors than are suitable for a Motherboard but not suitable for loads using Step-up voltage or boost regulators.  While it boosts the voltage it also boosts the primary load current and this may cause an over current situation.

In order to debug, each step up regulator you have may need to be modified to have an inrush current limiter (see ICL's at Digikey) inserted in series which can be inexpensive solution. There may be other instabilities created with the dynamic pulsed loads of boost regulators that trigger over-voltage.

Debugging this problem without suitable tools such as a scope with debugging skills may be frustrating but necessary.